# How to import/use source files of a project from a node module?

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm making an npm package whose goal is to start a react app and display components that are in the source folder of the project where it's installed. I have a folder structure like this:

-node_modules
   -my_npm_package
         -src
            -my_react_app_start.js
-src
   -AReactComponent.js

`my_react_app_start` should render `AReactComponent` but I don't find any way to import it from this file. Is there any way to do this? Is it possible to make a npm package that "reads" the source files of the project where it's installed anyway?

I tried to use: `import AReactComponent from '../../../src/AReactComponent'` which doesn't work

Comment: It seems like a weird way to do something like this. Importing from src into node_modules is something I've never seen. Are you sure that is your goal?

Comment: Yep it feels weird to me too. I don't know, there may be other way to achieve that, but I'm not sure what the options are

Comment: I think you need to create a Higher Order Component as your npm package and then import it and pass your own component to it to render.